# Spelling fix (for Canadians)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, spelling

[image: favorites vs favourites]

Before you say this is an insignificant change and a waste of time, please read the countless "bug reports" on plural misuse.

---

Yes, this is a small change. But for the sake of the Canadians (and other countries that use `...our...` instead of `...or...`), can this be added to Preferences?

---

**In response to Oded:**

> Does this question match the criteria provided in the Meta FAQ?

*Criteria? Where Meta lives, there's basically no criteria.*

> Is this question accepted by the community, as reflected in upvotes, favorites, views, and answers?

*Not currently, but it could affect a significant number of users.*

> Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?

*I can learn that SE understands foreign countries' awkward spellings.*

Comment: If this happens, then I want a preference to change every occurrence of the word "Maths" to "Math" in every comment, answer, or question.

Comment: Might as well turn this question into a list of minor spelling preferences.

Comment: Don't forget bouunties and Stack Ouverflow.

Comment: I am Canadian, and am fine with the way it is.  The effort to value ratio just isn't there.

Comment: @Shog9 Pretty sure it’s spelt *mounties* in Canadianese.

Comment: +1 for wanting Stack to use the correct spelling! You know, "English"... Ahem (well, not really +1, because this is an insignificant change and a waste of time)

Answer (score 22):

This would require a fairly massive translation effort. We do have some support in the engine for such changes now, but the work required would be a waste without sufficient support.

[Stack Overflow in Canadian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64503/stack-overflow-in-canadian) was proposed a few years ago, but deleted due to lack of interest. If this bothers you enough, consider starting a new proposal.

Note that we would also need to hire a Canadian Community Manager to enable us to communicate with the folks using such a site, so if you're interested (and able to communicate effectively in both English *and* Canadian) send us your resume.

Comment: Stack Overflow in Canadian is way too broad anyway. Realistically, you'd need Stack Overflow in English Canadian, Stack Overflow in French Canadian, Stack Overflow in Chiac, probably a couple different Native languages, not to mention Stack Overflow in Newfie. Lots of Community Manager jobs opening up soon, I suppose.

Comment: +1 for "able to communicate effectively in both English and Canadian", eh?

Comment: *prepares her resume*

Answer (score 3):

No Humour for you.

This is Meta, [where we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).